# Google Docs API - Zend GData - Create new doc - 400 Bad Request - Unable to convert document - Intermittent

Tags: google-docs-api, zend-gdata

I am using Zend GData to upload documents to Google docs.

The code works fine, except once in a while, it raises exception:

```
400 Bad Request - Unable to convert document.
```

This is an intermittent issue. So I believe the code is not a problem.

```
try {
    $test=$sharedocs->insertEntry($dataShare, $uri, 'Zend_Gdata_Entry',$header);
} catch (Exception $e ) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit();
}
```

Here is the exception

```
    Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException Object
    (
        [_httpClientException:protected] => 
        [_response:protected] => Zend_Http_Response Object
            (
                [version:protected] => 1.1
                [code:protected] => 400
                [message:protected] => Bad Request
                [headers:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [Content-type] => text/html; charset=UTF-8
                        [Date] => Fri, 14 Dec 2012 23:32:18 GMT
                        [Expires] => Fri, 14 Dec 2012 23:32:18 GMT
                        [Cache-control] => private, max-age=0
                        [X-content-type-options] => nosniff
                        [X-frame-options] => SAMEORIGIN
                        [X-xss-protection] => 1; mode=block
                        [Server] => GSE
                        [Connection] => close
                    )
                [body:protected] => Unable to convert document.
            )
        [_previous:Zend_Exception:private] => 
        [message:protected] => Expected response code 200, got 400
    Unable to convert document.
        [string:Exception:private] => 
        [code:protected] => 0
        [file:protected] => /usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Gdata/App.php
        [line:protected] => 714
        [trace:Exception:private] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [file] => /usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Gdata.php
                        [line] => 219
                        [function] => performHttpRequest
                        [class] => Zend_Gdata_App
                        [type] => ->
                        [args] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => POST
                                [1] => https://docs.google.com/feeds/documents/private/full
                                [2] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="END_OF_PART"
                                        [1] => Slug: test.doc
                                        [2] => Content-Type: application/msword
                                        [3] => resourceId:4321
                                        [x-http-method-override] => 
                                        [authorization] => AuthSub token="xxxxx"
                                    )
                                [3] => 
        
          
          Room for Debate (12345)
        
                                [4] => application/atom+xml
                                [5] => 
                            )
                    )
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [file] => /usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Gdata/App.php
                        [line] => 905
                        [function] => performHttpRequest
                        [class] => Zend_Gdata
                        [type] => ->
                        [args] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => POST
                                [1] => https://docs.google.com/feeds/documents/private/full
                                [2] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="END_OF_PART"
                                        [1] => Slug: test.doc
                                        [2] => Content-Type: application/msword
                                        [3] => resourceId:4321
                                        [x-http-method-override] => 
                                    )
                                [3] => 
        
          
          Room for Debate (12345)
        
                                [4] => application/atom+xml
                            )
                    )
                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [file] => /usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Gdata/App.php
                        [line] => 980
                        [function] => post
                        [class] => Zend_Gdata_App
                        [type] => ->
                        [args] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 
        
          
          Room for Debate (12345)
        
                                [1] => 
                                [2] => 
                                [3] => 
                                [4] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="END_OF_PART"
                                        [1] => Slug: test.doc
                                        [2] => Content-Type: application/msword
                                        [3] => resourceId:4321
                                    )
                            )
                    )
                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [file] => /var/www/GoogleFunctions.php
                        [line] => 90
                        [function] => insertEntry
                        [class] => Zend_Gdata_App
                        [type] => ->
                        [args] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 
        
          
          Room for Debate (12345)
        
                                [1] => 
                                [2] => Zend_Gdata_Entry
                                [3] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="END_OF_PART"
                                        [1] => Slug: test.doc
                                        [2] => Content-Type: application/msword
                                        [3] => resourceId:4321
                                    )
                            )
                    )
                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [file] => /var/www/myPaper.php
                        [line] => 342
                        [function] => createNewDoc
                        [args] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Room for Debate (12345)
                                [1] => Zend_Gdata_Docs Object
                                    (
                                        [_defaultPostUri:protected] => https://docs.google.com/feeds/documents/private/full
                                        [_registeredPackages:protected] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => Zend_Gdata_Docs
                                                [1] => Zend_Gdata_Kind
                                                [2] => Zend_Gdata_Extension
                                                [3] => Zend_Gdata
                                                [4] => Zend_Gdata_App_Extension
                                                [5] => Zend_Gdata_App
                                            )
                                        [_httpClient:protected] => Zend_Gdata_HttpClient Object
                                            (
                                                [_authSubPrivateKeyId:Zend_Gdata_HttpClient:private] => 
                                                [_authSubToken:Zend_Gdata_HttpClient:private] => 1/xxxxx
                                                [_clientLoginToken:Zend_Gdata_HttpClient:private] => 
                                                [_clientLoginKey:Zend_Gdata_HttpClient:private] => 
                                                [_streamingRequest:protected] => 
                                                [config:protected] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [maxredirects] => 0
                                                        [strictredirects] => 1
                                                        [useragent] => Zend_Framework_Gdata/1.11.12
                                                        [timeout] => 10
                                                        [adapter] => Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Socket
                                                        [httpversion] => 1.1
                                                        [keepalive] => 
                                                        [storeresponse] => 1
                                                        [strict] => 1
                                                        [output_stream] => 
                                                        [encodecookies] => 1
                                                        [rfc3986_strict] => 
                                                    )
                                                [adapter:protected] => Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Socket Object
                                                    (
                                                        [socket:protected] => 
                                                        [connected_to:protected] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [0] => 
                                                                [1] => 
                                                            )
                                                        [out_stream:protected] => 
                                                        [config:protected] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [persistent] => 
                                                                [ssltransport] => ssl
                                                                [sslcert] => 
                                                                [sslpassphrase] => 
                                                                [sslusecontext] => 
                                                                [maxredirects] => 0
                                                                [strictredirects] => 1
                                                                [useragent] => Zend_Framework_Gdata/1.11.12
                                                                [timeout] => 10
                                                                [httpversion] => 1.1
                                                                [keepalive] => 
                                                                [storeresponse] => 1
                                                                [strict] => 1
                                                                [output_stream] => 
                                                                [encodecookies] => 1
                                                                [rfc3986_strict] => 
                                                            )

                                                        [method:protected] => POST
                                                        [_context:protected] => Resource id #10
                                                    )
                                                [uri:protected] => Zend_Uri_Http Object
                                                    (
                                                        [_username:protected] => 
                                                        [_password:protected] => 
                                                        [_host:protected] => docs.google.com
                                                        [_port:protected] => 443
                                                        [_path:protected] => /feeds/documents/private/full
                                                        [_query:protected] => 
                                                        [_fragment:protected] => 
                                                        [_regex:protected] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [escaped] => %[[:xdigit:]]{2}
                                                                [unreserved] => [A-Za-z0-9-_.!~*'()\[\]]
                                                                [segment] => (?:%[[:xdigit:]]{2}|[A-Za-z0-9-_.!~*'()\[\]:@&=+$,;])*
                                                                [path] => (?:\/(?:(?:%[[:xdigit:]]{2}|[A-Za-z0-9-_.!~*'()\[\]:@&=+$,;])*)?)+
                                                                [uric] => (?:%[[:xdigit:]]{2}|[A-Za-z0-9-_.!~*'()\[\];\/?:@&=+$,])
                                                            )

                                                        [_scheme:protected] => https
                                                    )
                                                [headers:protected] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [user-agent] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [0] => User-Agent
                                                                [1] => MyCompany-MyApp-1.0 Zend_Framework_Gdata/1.11.12
                                                            )
                                                        [content-type] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [0] => Content-Type
                                                                [1] => application/atom+xml
                                                            )
                                                        [slug] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [0] => Slug
                                                                [1] => test.doc
                                                            )
                                                        [resourceid] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [0] => resourceId
                                                                [1] => 4321
                                                            )
                                                        [authorization] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [0] => authorization
                                                                [1] => AuthSub token="1/xxxxx"
                                                            )
                                                        [accept-encoding] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [0] => Accept-encoding
                                                                [1] => identity
                                                            )
                                                        [content-length] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [0] => Content-Length
                                                                [1] => 273
                                                            )
                                                    )
                                                [method:protected] => POST
                                                [paramsGet:protected] => Array
                                                    (
                                                    )
                                                [paramsPost:protected] => Array
                                                    (
                                                    )
                                                [enctype:protected] => application/atom+xml
                                                [raw_post_data:protected] => 
        
          
          Room for Debate (12345)
        
                                                [auth:protected] => 
                                                [files:protected] => Array
                                                    (
                                                    )
                                                [body_field_order:protected] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [service] => SCALAR
                                                    )
                                                [cookiejar:protected] => 
                                                [last_request:protected] => POST /feeds/documents/private/full HTTP/1.1
    Host: docs.google.com
    Connection: close
    User-Agent: MyCompany-MyApp-1.0 Zend_Framework_Gdata/1.11.12
    Content-Type: application/atom+xml
    Slug: test.doc
    resourceId: 4321
    authorization: AuthSub token="1/xxxxx"
    Accept-encoding: identity
    Content-Length: 273

    
        
          
          Room for Debate (12345)
        
                                                [last_response:protected] => Zend_Http_Response Object
                                                    (
                                                        [version:protected] => 1.1
                                                        [code:protected] => 400
                                                        [message:protected] => Bad Request
                                                        [headers:protected] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [Content-type] => text/html; charset=UTF-8
                                                                [Date] => Fri, 14 Dec 2012 23:32:18 GMT
                                                                [Expires] => Fri, 14 Dec 2012 23:32:18 GMT
                                                                [Cache-control] => private, max-age=0
                                                                [X-content-type-options] => nosniff
                                                                [X-frame-options] => SAMEORIGIN
                                                                [X-xss-protection] => 1; mode=block
                                                                [Server] => GSE
                                                                [Connection] => close
                                                            )
                                                        [body:protected] => Unable to convert document.
                                                    )
                                                [redirectCounter:protected] => 0
                                                [_unmaskStatus:protected] => 
                                                [_queryBracketsEscaped:protected] => 1
                                            )
                                        [_majorProtocolVersion:protected] => 1
                                        [_minorProtocolVersion:protected] => 
                                        [_useObjectMapping:protected] => 1
                                    )
                            )
                    )
            )
        [previous:Exception:private] => 
    )
```

Comment: This is a live production site issue. I would really appreciate it if somebody from the google-docs-api team respond to this.

Comment: Anybody from Google looked at this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14288836/google-docs-drive-api-does-not-permit-a-new-document-to-be-inserted-into-a-new-g

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ohh, so I answered somebodys question on same lines and forgot to put it on my question. :D

(https://stackoverflow.com/a/14290948/1736522)
[Google Docs/Drive API does not permit a new document to be inserted into a new Google account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14288836/google-docs-drive-api-does-not-permit-a-new-document-to-be-inserted-into-a-new-g)